# google drive api, javascript list files returns nothing

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm just getting started with Drive API calls, and I'm trying to list my files.

So far, my function looks like this:

```
 var retrieveAllFiles = function () {
            var retrievePageOfFiles = function(request, result) {
                request.execute(function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    result = result.concat(resp.items);
                    var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                    console.log("nextPageToken ="+nextPageToken);
                    if (nextPageToken) {
                        request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'pageToken': nextPageToken});
                        retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
                    } else {
                        printFileList(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'maxResults': 10});
        console.log("initialRequest = "+initialRequest);
         retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
        }
```

In firebug, I see that the response looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "id": "gapiRpc",
  "result": {
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "etag": "\"vGmlhiWxP02tugPmRvLynwC_A0Y/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
  }
 }
]
```

This isn't what I expect, because my Drive contains two files.

Can anyone point out what my mistake is?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved this one myself it was a problem with scopes.

I was using

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

but this only grants access to files create with the app making the request.  To get access to all the files I had to add

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

I only figured it out by using another app and noticing it was asking for different scopes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was missing this piece and struggled a lot. This exactly is what was missing for me too.

Comment: Had the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178682/google-drive-get-root-file-and-folders-with-javascript-api-get-only-deleted/18195426#18195426 Thanks for the solution! Takes me hours to figure out what went wrong.